# How do you print arrays of double in C?

Tags: c, arrays

I've looked all over the place and I’m trying to find a way to print double array in my c program. I'm not trying to print Code 2d array but an array that is double.

here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printarray(double array[]){
   int i;
   for(int i=0;i<=5;i++){
        printf("%.2f\n",array[i])
   }
}

int main() {

    double array={1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0};

}
```

Comment: Start by learning to write valid C. How can a single `double` be an array?

Comment: what do you mean sir?

Comment: You also attempt to print 6 elements of a 5-element array; change `i<=5` to `i<5`. Better yet, pass the length of the array as a second parameter.

Comment: Keep reading, and learn new stuff. There is a long way to go. Don't look for others to help even on small issues like this. It's the effort that you give to learning (by discovering stuff by yourself), that makes you a good programmer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Working code below. You should usually pass the size of the array as a 2nd parameter. But this is the basic functionality that I guess you want happening.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(double array[])
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i<5; i++)
    {
      printf("%.2f ", array[i]);
    }
}


int main()
{

  double myArray[5] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};

  printArray(myArray);

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No explanation? No mention that the array length should be a parameter?

Comment: I added that a minute ago, he didn't really want an explanation, he just wanted to print a double array.

Comment: His errors were pretty small too, based off this he can probably understand and do this himself, and if not add on more functionalities. Computer Science is all about understanding and implementing yourself, I think he knows the basics of what he wrote, and can understand his mistakes and semantics based off this WORKING example.

Answer (score 2):

**Errors**

1. The line

   ```
   printf("%.2f\n",array[i])
   ```

   doesn't end with a semicolon `;`.
2. You aren't defining the array in a correct manner. For array definition you need to use `[]`. So the definition should be

   ```
   double array[] = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0};
   ```

**Warnings**

1. You might not have provided the full code, but you have never called `printarray` function.
2. You are declaring `int i` two times.
3. There are only 5 elements in the array so in the for loop, your test should be `i < 5` and not `i <= 5`.
4. Finally, I suggest that you should supply an function prototype instead.

Here's the nicely formatted new code

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printarray(double[]);

int main(void) {
    double array[] = {1.0,2.0,3.0,4.0,5.0};
    printarray(array);

    return 0;
}

void printarray(double array[]) {
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        printf("%.2f\n",array[i]);
    }
}
```